# Removing noise line in captcha image to solve complex captcha image

Tags: opencv, line, captcha, python-tesseract, noise

I want to delete the random noise line in captcha iamge.
There are several captcha samples in below.

[image: test1]

[image: test2]

[image: test3]

I utilized cv2 and pytesseract.

```
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(gry, 'gray')
plt.show()
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w*2, h*2))
plt.imshow(gry, 'gray')
plt.show()

cls = cv2.morphologyEx(gry, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, None)
# cls = cv2.morphologyEx(gry, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, None)
plt.imshow(cls, 'gray')
plt.show()
val, thr = cv2.threshold(cls, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
val,thr = cv2.threshold(cls, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# val, thr = cv2.threshold(cls, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# val, thr = cv2.threshold(cls, 0, 255, 8 )
plt.imshow(thr, 'gray')
plt.show()
print(val)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4,8))
morph_img = cv2.morphologyEx(thr, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
plt.imshow(morph_img, 'gray')
plt.show()

txt = image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)
txt = image_to_string(morph_img)
print(txt)
```

The result.

[image: result]

As I see the result, It's hard to remove some noise lines which hard to predict '7','E'.

Is there any good solution to solve the captcha?

Please recommend a method to deal with some harmful lines!

**++**
**data URL path is encoded with base64 like this:**

> data:image/png;base64,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

When I changed some encrypted alphabet in base64 text, the portion of the image was changed. It can be a tiny solution to solve captcha?

Comment: a good solution involves deep learning. needn't be terribly deep. the network only has to learn to recognize the letters and numbers and to ignore the distractions.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the comment. I tried to build the deep learning model, but the dataset is not enough too. It is an important thing that manages to preprocess the data used as input to the model. Any method needs to preprocess to remove line.

Comment: @nathancy Awesome! I need to do an effort to use the cv2 library or a thing that can control the image. Thanks for your comment :)